# SQLXML to XML to read values

Tags: java, sqlxml

I have some java code.  Part of it is as follows:

```
        try (ResultSet rs = Query.OpenQuery(conn, query);) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                rem = rs.getString("ReturnedRemarkCode");
                SQLXML xmlSource = rs.getSQLXML("htmlrequest");
                xmlAsText = xmlSource.getString();
```

The html request is, as you guessed, an HTML request.  When I look at the value of xmlAsText it shows the entire request in ASCII.  I can operate on an ASCII string but it is a lot harder to get elements.  I have to do somthing like
     **txt.replaceAll("^.*<returnCode>","").replaceAll("</returnCode>.*$","");** but this is kind of bulky.

The only method I can find in SQLXML is getString();  What I am looking for is something like **getElement("//returnCode")** or something similar to that to get the specified element value.  Google searches have not really helped.

Anybody have experience with this? As I said, replaceAll() as above will work but is complex.

Comment: You'll have to parse the SQLXML object into an actual XML document. Read the [Javadocs for SQLXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html) for some examples using the platform-provided XML parsers, but this same concept could apply to any XML library you would like to use.

Comment: I tried.  It got too complicated so I decided to just use the ASCII (or whatever you call it now ;-))